# Limit of $t_ne^{-at_n}$, where $t_n$ is a divergent sequence and $a>0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $t_n$ be a sequence such that $t_n \to + \infty$ and $a>0$, then
$t_ne^{-at_n}$ is divergent or convergent?
I think it goes to $0$, because $e^{at_n}$ grows faster than $t_n$. But I am not sure.

Comment: Do you know L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: Yes, but I do not know how $t_n$ looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution without using L'Hopital's Rule: From the series expansion of $e^{x}$ we get $e^{-at_n} =\frac  1 {e^{at_n}} \leq \frac  2 {a^{2}t_n^{2}}$. So  the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $t_n\to \infty$,
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{t_n}{e^{at_n}}=\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{t}{e^{at}}.
$$
This can be calculated by L'Hopital's rule as
$$
\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{1}{ae^{at}}=0.
$$

Comment: @NaN Why isn't it?

Comment: the sequence $t_n$ could consist of terms that aren't of the form $f(n)$ for a differentiable $f$.

Comment: I just thought it would definetly be important to mention this in the post, since it is not a general solution, even though it is of course an elegant one in some situations.

Comment: @NaN You may be misunderstanding the use of L'Hopital's rule. It is easy to prove that the sequence limit is equal to $\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{t}{e^{at}}$ if this exists. L'Hopital's rule is then used to compute this limit of this differentiable function.

Comment: I am terribly sorry for that mistake, of course you are correct here.